# resolving inconsistent behaviour observed in converting a standalone list function to a method of a new class in Python

Tags: python, list, function, class, methods

I'm trying to convert a standalone function for updating one list using another list to a method of a new class that inherits from the `list` class. I've nearly got it working, but I'm getting something small wrong and I don't see how to fix it.

The function idea is to update one list using another. This means that an existing pair of values in the list gets updated or a new pair of values gets appended as appropriate. Below shows the function in use, updating list `a` with list `b`:

```
>>> def update(
...     originalPairs,
...     updatePairs
...     ):
...     for updatePair in range(len(updatePairs)):
...         found_match = False
...         for pair in range(len(originalPairs)):
...             # If there is a matching 'key' in a pair of the existing list of
...             # pairs, record that a match was found and update the existing pair.
...             if updatePairs[updatePair][0] == originalPairs[pair][0]:
...                 found_match = True
...                 originalPairs[pair][1] = updatePairs[updatePair][1]
...         # If a matching 'key' is not found, there is no pair to update. Append
...         # the update pair to the existing list of pairs.
...         if not found_match:
...             originalPairs.append(updatePairs[updatePair])
... 
>>> a = [['Adolf', '10'], ['Hermann', '20'], ['Heinrich', '30'], ['Heinrich', '15']]
>>> b = [['Rudolf', '40'], ['Adolf', '50']]
>>> update(a, b)
>>> a
[['Adolf', '50'], ['Hermann', '20'], ['Heinrich', '30'], ['Heinrich', '15'], ['Rudolf', '40']]
```

I'm trying to convert these ideas to a class. The update function has been converted to a method:

```
>>> import sys
>>> class pairs(list):
...     def __init__(
...         self,
...         *args
...         ):
...         # list initialisation
...         if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
...             super().__init__(self, *args)
...         else:
...             super(pairs, self).__init__(self, *args)
...     def update(
...         self,
...         updatePairs
...         ):
...         for updatePair in range(len(updatePairs)):
...             found_match = False
...             for pair in range(len(self)):
...                 # If there is a matching 'key' in a pair of the existing list of
...                 # pairs, record that a match was found and update the existing
...                 # pair.
...                 if updatePairs[updatePair][0] == self[pair][0]:
...                     found_match   = True
...                     self[pair][1] = updatePairs[updatePair][1]
...             # If a matching 'key' is not found, there is no pair to update.
...             # Append the update pair to the existing list of pairs.
...             if not found_match:
...                 self.append(updatePairs[updatePair])
... 
>>> a = pairs()
>>> a.append([['Adolf', '10'], ['Hermann', '20'], ['Heinrich', '30'], ['Heinrich', '15']])
>>> b = pairs()
>>> b.append([['Rudolf', '40'], ['Adolf', '50']])
>>> a
[[['Adolf', '10'], ['Hermann', '20'], ['Heinrich', '30'], ['Heinrich', '15']]]
>>> b
[[['Rudolf', '40'], ['Adolf', '50']]]
>>> a.update(b)
>>> a
[[['Adolf', '10'], ['Hermann', '20'], ['Heinrich', '30'], ['Heinrich', '15']], [['Rudolf', '40'], ['Adolf', '50']]]
```

You can see that the append functionality is working, but it is not *updating* values as it should. What is going wrong here?

Comment: `a.append` is adding the nested list as a single element, I think you want `a.extend`. Look more carefully at the structures when you show `a` (before and after `update`) and `b`. Also, what should `a.update([['Heinrich', '25']])` do - update one (which?) or both?

Comment: You're dead right. I didn't look for the extra bracket. Thanks again! Regarding the possible update of duplicate pairs, I'm going to add protection against that usage (or possibly overwrite all); I just wanted to keep the code in question simple.

Comment: You're also making a mistake in `__init__` - you don't need to pass `self` to `super(...).__init__`, just `*args`. Then you don't have to `extend` at all, just e.g. `b = pairs([['Rudolf', '40'], ['Adolf', '50']])`. Unless you *really need* duplicates, a mapping (`dict`) would be a much more sensible and efficient structure.

Comment: I think you are supposed to inherit from `collections.UserList` for sub-classing `list`.